# How to remove the background on a MS Visio Page

Tags: vba, visio

**How can I remove the background on an MS Visio page?**

I've been searching for a way to create a simple white background, but have not come across a working solution. The most straight forward .Background parameter doesn't seem to correspond to the background that I can set manually in the Design Ribbon.

```
Dim i As Integer
With objVisio.ActiveDocument
    For i = 1 To .Pages.Count
        .Pages(i).ThemeColors = 2 'Blue colors
        .Pages(i).ThemeEffects = 2
        .Pages(i).Background = False
    Next i
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`BackPage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff768366.aspx) property.  For example:

```
.Pages(i).BackPage = ""
```

[`Page.Background`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff769181.aspx) is a property to tell you whether a page is a background page or not.

Comment: I had already tried this, but the background in the org chart remains filled with the little squares... which now that I'm writing it I'm beginning to think are equivalent to the "cells" in excel.

Comment: Is it possible that in order to have a "white" background I need to ADD a white background?

Comment: I wonder if you're talking about the grid?  Have you looked at [Window.ShowGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff765682(v=office.15).aspx) ? If not you might want to add an image so we can see what you're refering to.

Comment: It is indeed the Grid! Thanks for you help!